# Use environment variable in expect spawn command

Tags: linux, expect

I'm trying to use expect to run a command, but with a specific set of environment variables. Here's what it looks like:

```
expect -c "spawn \"NODE_ENV=production node script.js\"; expect eof"
```

But this fails, with the following error:

```
spawn NODE_ENV=production node script.js
couldn't execute "NODE_ENV=production node script.js": no such file or directory
while executing "spawn "NODE_ENV=production node script.js""
```

The command works if I remove the environment variable, but I don't know how else to set it before running the command?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expect -c 'spawn bash -c "NODE_ENV=production node script.js"; expect eof'
```

Comment: Or perhaps `spawn env NODE_ENV=production node script.js`

Comment: Or `NODE_ENV=production expect -c 'spawn node script.js; expect eof'`

Comment: Also, `expect -c 'set env(NODE_ENV) production; ...'`